# Why object destructuring in javascript will affect scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, scope

I am trying to understand why object destructuring is changing the scope?

```
(function() {
    var o = {
        add: function(a , b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        log: function () {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
    var { log } = o;
    o.log();
    log();
})();
```

this code will log two different objects

the first one is object o as expected but the second will log the global object

UPDATE (3 - May - 2021):
If you have the same question and looking for a more detailed answer, read this one as well:
[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work#answer-3127440)

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with destructuring, but rather with bound (`o.log()`) vs unbound  (`log()`) calls. You'll get the right `this` only with the former.

Comment:  this is a good fundamental question for interviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's not exactly right

```js
function log() {
  console.log('na aahh')
}
(function() {
    var o = {
        add: function(a , b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        log: function () {
            console.log('hi, i am locally scoped');
        }
    }
    var { log } = o;
    o.log();
    log();
})();
```

Run and see.

But...when you log `this` it always takes on the nearest scope which happens to be global because its detached from the `o` when destructured.

Try doing something like this...

```js
function log() {
  console.log('nananana')
}
(function() {
    var o = {
        add: function(a , b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        log: function () {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
    o.log = o.log.bind(o);
    var { log } = o;
    o.log();
    log();
})();
```

and notice how it retains `this` on destructure.

Also... side note, you should use `let` over using `var` as `let` when declared also has block scope which is pretty nice.

Happy coding sir.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is more or less equivalent of

```
const log = o.log
```

You have extracted a method from an object, but trying to call it without doing anything else, `this` will not refer to the original object. You need to `bind` it.

```
const log = o.log.bind(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you set `this` to be:

```
(function() {
var o = {
    add: function(a , b) {
        return a + b;
    },
    log: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
var { log } = o;
o.log();
// equivalent to
log.call(o);
})();
```